# Android studio gradle: DSL method not found 'packageNameSuffix'

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, build.gradle

I am trying to run an android project in android studio using Gradle. When I try to run the build.gradle file, the error:

[image: Gradle error]

Does someone know why the problem could be? I am suspecting my gradle configuration is not right, as this is a project that runs perfectly for someone else. 
This is the build.graddle file:

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    maven { url 'http://repo1.maven.org/maven2' }
    mavenCentral()
}
dependencies {
    //classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.6.+'
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.1.0'
}
}
apply plugin: 'android'

repositories {
    maven {
        url 'https://github.com/Goddchen/mvn-repo/raw/master/'
    }
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:13.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:3.1.36'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.2.4'
    //compile 'com.codeslap:persistence:0.9.24'
    compile 'org.apache.commons:commons-io:1.3.2'
    compile 'com.nostra13.universalimageloader:universal-image-loader:1.8.4'
    //compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook:3.5.2'
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook:3.17.1'
    compile files('libs/rollbar-android-0.0.6.jar')
    compile files('libs/libGoogleAnalyticsV2.jar')
    //compile files('libs/commons-codec-1.7-SNAPSHOT-android.jar')
    compile files('libs/tinylinetry_and.jar')
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 18
    buildToolsVersion '19.1.0'

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 18
    }

    signingConfigs {
        release {
            storeFile file("../keystore.jks")
            storePassword "******"
            keyAlias "Android Release Key"
            keyPassword "******"
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        debug {
            applicationIdSuffix ".debug"
        }
        release {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Try updating your gradle

Comment: post your build.gradle

Answer (score 0):

-Usually, you will see this error when you are using Gradle version 0.10 or higher and your buildTypes debug has packageNameSuffix ".debug".  Seems like your build file is already changed to applicationIdSuffix ".debug".  That makes me think,  that the build.gradle file posted above is not the corresponding file used when you got the error message posted.